# How to use a fixed height for UIImageView in a tableViewHeader with Scale to Fill mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uitableview, xcode5

- iOS 6+
- Using Auto Layout
- Table View with Header and Footer because cells in between are static (static cells are only supported in a UITableViewController, not a UITableView in a normal UIViewController..)

In IB I set the height of the UIImageView to 140. The image that I load into it is square.
I want to use scale to fill and see a portion of the image, as long as the entire UIImageView is filled. There is no way to use constraints on this header view, not in IB, not programatically (tried).

The issue is that probably because of Auto Layout, the UIImageView gets stretched until the image fits entirely in the UIImageView. In fact the image view is even stretched over the first couple of rows of the table view's body.

How can I get around this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed by checking "Clip Subviews" in IB.

Answer (score -1):

try play with [UIView setContentMode:]

Comment: Doesn't work. Same issue, image gets full aspect instead of UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill while maintaining the limited height.